# Swift, AVplayer doesn't play file from "Documents" folder

Tags: swift, swiftui, avplayer

I'm trying to play a video from "Documents" folder and AVPlayer does not want to play it. No error messages, just a blank screen.

It used to work well when I was playing files from "resources" [`Bundle.main.path(forResource: exerciseItem.exercise!.v_video, ofType:"mp4")`] but now I need to play a newly downloaded file.

PS: I tried prependnig "file://" to the file path but it didn't work. Even though i am 100% sure the file exists.

```
            let asset = AVAsset(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String + "/" + exerciseItem.exercise!.v_video!))
            let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)

            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidFinishPlaying), name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: playerItem)

            self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
            self.player.isMuted = true
            self.player.play()
```

I wonder if a different approach should be used to play files from local filesystem?

Also, my file has a name "4AMShKRkB2Lw69tdT7q2" (no mp4 extension).

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You should not be using NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains at all, and definitely never say `+ "/" +`. Form your reference correctly as a URL. — "Even though i am 100% sure the file exists." Please show why you are so sure of that. How did this file end up in Documents, exactly? That doesn't happen by itself.

Comment: i double checked with my FileExists function using the same URL/filepath and it returned "true".

Comment: The file was downloaded from Firebase Storage and i can see it on my local drive, i also copied it to my personal download folder and checked if it's not corrupted - it's not. The file hasn't been changed while being downloaded.